# Sending an MS Teams message using the Microsoft Graph API or BOT API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to implement the following solution: a web application that subscribes to all MS teams chat messages. If a message contains forbidden text, the application should somehow warn the user (Ideally by replying to the same message, or, if not possible, initiate a conversation with the user).

I'm able to receive all chat webhooks and process them, but I could not find any way to post a message back to the Teams channel using the Graph API (the operation described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messagereply?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
is not supported for Application permissions - only delegated ones which isn't suitable for our case).

So I'm trying to send proactive messages using the Bot framework, However, the bot framework requires a teams conversation ID which I don't have (the graph API webhook provides the team, channel and user IDs, none of which are accepted by the Bot API).

Does anyone know of a way I can retrieve the teams conversation ID using the team ID and channel ID provided by the graph API?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConversationId for channel messages are combination of channelId and messageId both can be found in payload you get [webhook notification](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/announcing-change-notifications-for-microsoft-teams-messages/). You can reply to existing conversation by using following by building converstionId like this:

```
 conversationId =   $"{channelId};messageid={messageId}"
```

For reply to work, your Bot needs to installed in the team and should have [serviceURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#base-uri) saved at some place to refer back. Here is sample code which show how you can reply to existing message.

```
var serviceURL = "YOUR Service URL- You get this in each bot payload";
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(serviceURL, DateTime.MaxValue);
using var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceURL, MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword);


var conversationId = $"{channelId};messageid={messageId}";
var replyActivity = MessageFactory.Text($"This is simple reply to existing conversation.");
replyActivity.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId);
var response = await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationId, replyActivity);
```

For 1:1 reply- please take a look at [Sending Proactive Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#examples) documentation.

Comment: Do you know if there is any solution for posting messages to private chats by an API. We would like to be able to monitor those as well and warn users when forbidden data is disclosed in a private chat.

Comment: you can use the same mechanism (proactive messaging), but be aware that your bot needs to be installed into every relevant private chat